# How to build skia library for ios with 64 bit support

Tags: ios, arm64, skia

I'm trying to build skia library for ios.

The xcode project generate command `GYP_DEFINES="skia_os='ios' skia_arch_type='arm' armv7=1 arm_neon=0" ./gyp_skia` always return `GYP_GENERATORS environment variable not set, using default`, does this mean the config variables are not set?

And also, how do I add arm64 support? I tried `skia_arch_type='arm64'`, didn't seem the way to go.